# How to rebuild godef to work with Go 1.4

Tags: go

After I upgraded to Go 1.4, `godef` is no longer finding many things in the standard libraries, for instance `Testing.Fatalf`.

When I try to `go get -u`, I get these errors:

```
package code.google.com/p/goplan9/plan9/acme
    imports code.google.com/p/goplan9/plan9/acme
    imports code.google.com/p/goplan9/plan9/acme: cannot find package "code.google.com/p/goplan9/plan9/acme" in any of:
    /Users/bryan/local/go/src/code.google.com/p/goplan9/plan9/acme (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/bryan/sweng/oms/src/code.google.com/p/goplan9/plan9/acme (from $GOPATH)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to edit this file because a dependency has moved:

```
--- a/exp/cmd/godef/acme.go
+++ b/exp/cmd/godef/acme.go
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 package main

 import (
-   "code.google.com/p/goplan9/plan9/acme"
+   "9fans.net/go/acme"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
```

Then `go build` and `go install` and all working great once more.

Comment: I believe this has now been fixed in the main godef repository.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue, I edited godef.go though.

```
--- a/exp/cmd/godef/godef.go  2015-01-19 15:29:10.760304470 -0500
+++ b/exp/cmd/godef/godef.go  2015-02-10 21:36:29.678102962 -0500
@@ -47,7 +47,7 @@
        }
        r := runtime.GOROOT()
        if r != "" {
-               gopath = append(gopath, r+"/src/pkg")
+               gopath = append(gopath, r+"/src")
        }
        types.GoPath = gopath
}
```